# Checkbox keeps autockecking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I have a problem that I can`t really figure out. I have this todo list and I am required to have checkbox. The problem is that if I have the top task checked and then I remove it, the following task get checked by itself.

If I use a button instead of checkbox the functionability works with no problem, but I am required to have a checkbox. Any ideas why? There is a like with the codesandbox below. Thank you!

https://codesandbox.io/s/student-frontend-developer-template-forked-jupcx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It is easier if you give us the code you tried.

Comment: I figure it out. It was a problem with the input check box. 

 <input
            readOnly
            type="checkbox"
            onClick={() => completeTodo(todo.id)}
            checked={todo.completed}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `key` to `todo.id` instead of `id` (Avoid using **index** as keys , especially where you're removing items in an array and using the same array to render stuff) :-

```
<Todo
key={todo.id}
id={id}
todo={todo}
completeTodo={completeTodo}
 removeTodo={removeTodo}
 />
```

Read more about the *whys* here - https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Would you say it's safe to use index as keys if the data is never changed?

Comment: I think for read-only lists like some **info** points whose data origin is not a **back-end** but in front-end itself, that's where you can probably use `index` as keys. Mostly you have unique ids coming from backend, so always go for using those ids as keys.